# Install Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Hy, I am new in `Phonegap`.

I have downloaded the **cordova-2.2.0**. Where should I paste it?

And I just extracted **incubator-cordova-android** and **incubator-cordova-docs** folder because I just want to develop `Android` project.

I am using **windows OS** , how to create a new project?

The [`Phonegap`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android_4_setup_new_project) just teaching using terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [Getting started with PhoneGap in Eclipse for Android ](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html) Check this video tutorial [Your first android application with Phone Gap - Part 1 ](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=519auOITpzM) for more information

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is `Phonegap` support **Windows XP**?
I cannot find any **Windows XP** folder for the `js` and `jar`.

Comment: yes You can develop in windows. there is no need of any external set up. just put your cardova.jar in libs folder and put your index.html in assests.

Comment: Where can I find the cordova.jar?
**cordova-2.2.0\incubator-cordova-android** has no any cordova.jar

Comment: click [this](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/#download)